# Failed to add an image to a sqlite database?

Tags: xcode, image, sqlite, addition

there is the code to insert image with to other fields :

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"recette.jpg"];
            NSData *image2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone,image) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\" )", name.text, address.text, phone.text,image2];
```

thinks

Comment: I have nothing missing because it works without image I just put some code to explain ,this not the entire code

Answer (score 2):

Images need to be added as blob objects

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"recette.jpg"];
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

char *update = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone,image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbpath, update, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name.text, -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, address.text, -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, phone.text, -1, NULL);
        if(imgData != nil)
            sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 4, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
        else
            sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 4, nil, -1, NULL);

 }
 else if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
     char *errorMsg;
     NSAssert1(0, @"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
}

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: +1, it might be better at times to store only the location of the image though. (that way, the image doesn't have to be send around as much)

Comment: it works perfectly sorry I have changed the name of the bd and it works :)